# MySQL Connector (Mac) returning Hex instead of String

Tags: tableau-api, mysql-connector

I was screwing around trying to get Excel on the Mac to get to MySql data the other day, but just realized today that Tableau (my primary use of the Mysql Connector) is returning my blob columns as hex strings...not normal text strings as it usually does.

I cannot figure out how to set characterEncoding on the connector side. Nothing changed on the server side. Any help would be much appreciated. Using mysql connector 8.00.0020 and iodbc to facilitate use.

Answer (score 0):

reverted to 5.3 and it worked fine